# Expressing "there is none" in universe discourse

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I'm attempting to express:

There is no Vans that are fast and turbocharged.

The domain of this is all vans. $V$

$F(v)$ is fast

$T(v)$ is turbocharged

Is the correct way to equate this, as following?

$$\forall v (\neg F(v) \land \neg T(v))$$

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Comment: Remember, there could exist a fast van that isn't turbocharged and a turbocharged van that isn't fast.

Comment: Change the and to an or to make it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence you've written expresses, "Every van has the property that it is not fast and not turbocharged." You're wanting

$$\neg \exists v (F(v) \wedge T(v))$$

which expresses that, "We cannot find a van that is both fast and turbocharged."

**Exercise**. Rewrite the above statement in the form: $\forall v[\mbox{something}]$.

Comment: But after negating  $$\neg \exist (F(v) \wedge T(v))$$ We get $$\forall v (\neg F(v) \vee \neg T(v))$$ by moving the negation into the proposition. Would this change the prop?

Comment: @GivenPie Actually, they're not negations of one another. They're logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can restate this as "there does not exist any van which is fast and which is turbocharged also."  How do you express "there does not exist"?